# How Can I new a value_type pointer?

Tags: c++

I am writing a serialize and deserialize method, and I encountered a problem in the implementation of `deserialize`: I can't `new` a `value_type`, which is actually a `Skill*`.

```
template <class T >
static istream &DeSerializePVector(istream& istream_, T& container)
{
  typedef typename T::value_type ElementType;
  size_t size;
  istream_ >> size;
  container.reserve(size);
  container.resize(size);

  for(typename T::iterator ite = container.begin(); ite != container.end(); ite++)
  {
     *ite = new *ElementType;   //how can  I initialize this type?
     (*ite)->DeSerialize(istream_);
  }

  return istream_;
}

int main()
{
    Skill*  disease = Factory::CreateSkill ( SKILLTYPE_DISEASE );
    Skill*  purify = Factory::CreateSkill ( SKILLTYPE_PURIFY );
    Skill* skills[2] = {disease, purify};
    vector<Skill*> int_vector = Tools::MakeVector ( skills );
    ofstream fileOut;
    fileOut.open ( "data.txt", std::ofstream::binary );

    ISerializable::SerializePVector( fileOut, int_vector );
    fileOut.flush();
    fileOut.close();

    ifstream fileIn;
    vector<Skill*> int_vector2;
    fileIn.open ( "data.txt", std::ofstream::binary );
    ISerializable::DeSerializePVector( fileIn, int_vector2 );
}
```

How am I supposed to get this work?

Comment: The correct syntax would be `new ElementType;` (without the asterisk between "new" and "ElementType"). Is that the problem? Or are you asking how to decide which constructor to use? `new ElementType` means you call the default constructor.

Comment: As far as I can tell from the code, you have already allocated these objects. *ite is either disease or purify. In which case you don't need the line '*ite = new ElementType' at all, just call through to DeSerialize which I assume is going to actually populate these objects with data.

Comment: I can`t new SKill*.. If a put Skill in vector,then you are right.

Comment: When I resize vector<Skill*> ,actually there is no default construct to call :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `ElementType` has a default constructor, then

```
*ite = new ElementType;
```

It `ElementType` is already a pointer type, then you may need this (C++11):

```
#include <type_traits>

*ite = new typename std::remove_pointer<ElementType>::type;
```

If you don't have C++11 support, you can use the `boost` equivalent.

Comment: But The type_value is SKill* which is a point. I can`t new  Skill*.

Comment: @ZK_ Why can't you `new Skill*`

Comment: @ZK_ so `ElemenType` = `Skill*`?

Comment: Xcode complains that "Assigning to "Skill*" from incompatible type 'ElementType *(aka 'Skill**'),;dereference with *